# Unable to delete the bin directory in Filezilla

Tags: filezilla, folder-permissions

In filezilla I used to upload the website contents for our project from today it is showing that you can't delete this directories. But the thing is yesterday only I have uploaded correctly and website also worked correctly.From today it is not displaying correctly and if I trying to delete that bin folder and to upload new one it is showing error 550 Permission Denied.Also I tried to change the file permission to `777` to delete and renaming this dll files within this directory but not used.

This is the error list:

```
Directory listing successful

Command:    DELE C1.Web.UI.Controls.3.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/C1.Web.UI.Controls.3.dll: Permission denied.

Command: DELE C1.Web.UI.3.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/C1.Web.UI.3.dll: Permission denied.

Command:    DELE App_Web_u5crbnjm.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/App_Web_u5crbnjm.dll: Permission denied.

Command:    DELE App_Web_qxfqrmxk.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/App_Web_qxfqrmxk.dll: Permission denied.

Command:    DELE App_Web_li5d1wds.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/App_Web_li5d1wds.dll: Permission denied.

Command:    DELE App_Web_e0gqgzvi.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/App_Web_e0gqgzvi.dll: Permission denied.

Command:    DELE App_Web_coj1jirv.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/App_Web_coj1jirv.dll: Permission denied.

Command:    DELE App_Web_00hzknjy.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/App_Web_00hzknjy.dll: Permission denied.

Command:    DELE App_Licenses.dll
Response:   550 /bin_no/App_Licenses.dll: Permission denied.

Command:    CWD /
Response:   250 Directory changed to /?

Command:    RMD bin_no
Response:   550 /bin_no: Cannot delete directory.**
```

And, now I can even upload the new bin directory.

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Do you know, this is a programming QA site, right?. Does your question have something related to programming? (in C# and NET ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely accessing an FTP server hosted on Windows. On Windows, unlike on Unix, files which are in use cannot be removed. So if the application running your website loaded those DLL files, you first need to make it unload them.

FileZilla issues a `DELE`, the FTP server translates this to some kind of `unlink` command for the OS. The OS refuses to delete the file as it still is loaded. It's not the fault of FileZilla nor of the FTP server.

Comment: Now to do for this.Shall i try to upload again?

Comment: Another thing is now i'm not able to upload new bin directory...

Comment: @user5204800 My guess is you shut down the web application. If that does not work, reboot the server but make sure the web application is NOT started. Then you can replace/remove the files and start the web application again.

Comment: @user5204800 If the answer helped you, mark it as accepted answer. This way, your question will be marked as answered.

Comment: Actually files are not uploaded correctly. After they uploaded, we can able to delete them.